# Wordpress category post url like categoryname-postname

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress site and i want my category post urls be like this :

> http://www.sitename/category_name-postname

Also i want to remove category base from your url. I have given dot (.) in category base, its working fine but when i write `/%category%-%postname%` instead of `/%category%/%postname%`, it gives 404 page not found.

So anyone know how to set category post url seperated by dash, not slash. Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is how we match the `category_name`? It's nearly impossible with unpredictable categories.

Comment: Well is it to set this type of url for any single category not all. i mean via rewrite url or any trick inside htaccess?

Comment: /%category%-%postname% it's working , i have set in my local wp permalink structure like /%category%-%postname% and used get_permalink(your_post_id) in template file.